# Undefined PHP Constant in require_once() in IntelliJ IDEA 11

Tags: php, zend-framework, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA 11. Most of the PHP-Files of my Zend-Project start with something like:

```
require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/businessobjects/Car.php');
```

The IDE mentions two Warnings on this line:

- Undefined Constant APPLICATION_PATH
- Path "businessobjects" not found

As a Consequence, when I hover "new Car()" the IDE tells me "Undefined class Car".

How can I solve this Issue?

Comment: Define the constant `APPLICATION_PATH` before the `require_once()` call, and set it to the correct value. `define( 'APPLICATION_PATH', 'SOME VALUE');`. Unless you're not supposed to be accessing these files directly, and they're supposed to be `include()`'d from another PHP file that defines the constant.

Comment: IIRC IntelliJ (here: PHPStorm, you might have the PHP Plugin) does not resolve string concatenation to pathnames. So I dunno even if the constant is defined, the problem is solved. But would be nice to know.

Comment: @Hakre It does resolve .. but it works weird (sometimes works, sometimes does not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I had another Issue with IntelliJ IDEA which has been discussed [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147336/how-to-get-intellij-idea-to-display-directories) (IntelliJ did not display any Folders in the Project Tree). After I added all of my Files as one single "WebModule" and IntelliJ finished Indexing all these Folders and Files, it perfectly found the Path to my businessobjects and the Class "Car".

Answer (score 1):

The path issue is related to the APPLICATION_PATH constant not being defined, as it prepends the path passed to require_once.

Probably, ZEND is expecting you to have defined the APPLICATION_PATH constant, perhaps like this:

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', __DIR__);
```

(See: [PHP Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php))

You can also test if that constant is defined, like thus:

```
if (!defined('APPLICATION_PATH')) {
    // it's not defined, so define it!
} else {
    // proceed as usual
}
```

I'm not too familiar with IntelliJ IDEA / Zend, but chances are there is a config file missing which defines the APPLICATION_PATH.

See also: [Google search for zend config APPLICATION_PATH](https://www.google.com/search?q=zend%20config%20APPLICATION_PATH&aq=f&oq=zend%20config%20APPLICATION_PATH&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)