# Cloned a Java project to IntelliJ , now I can't see any source files

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea

So me and a friend decied to try out IntelliJ for our next project instead of Eclipse but we are having some issues.

At first I created the project on my computer(lets call i com1) in eclipse, created repo on github and pushed it. This worked just fine. On my com2 I cloned the repo to eclipse and continued working, no issues whatsoever.

Then I installed IntelliJ and just imported the project that was already on com1. This worked fine aswell. Then on com2, I cloned the repo from github and the problems started to arise. IntelliJ failed to find my main class and my main method. After 3 hours of searching I just couldn't get it to work. I removed the repo, the project and all on both machines. Created a new repo and made a new project, copied over my src files and pushed it to the new repo on com2. Now that works fine, then I started com1 and cloned the repo, and now all I can se in the project explorer is the .gitignore file and the External Libaries folder.

What am I doing wrong here? I just want to code but using git and github takes so much time for me.

Comment: Have you considered using a build tool, like Maven or Gradle? There's a chance that internal project files of Eclipse or IntelliJ contain absolute file paths and just don't work well when moved from one place to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem some time ago. The solution was to create a module inside IntelliJ (File->New Module). Try if it helps.
[Stack solution link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147336/how-to-get-intellij-idea-to-display-directories)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use maven or gradle? You can import the maven/gradle project instead of importing just source code and folders.

Using such tools can help you to abstract from any IDE.