# Show directories Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, directory

All at once directories became invisible. What is wrong with my project?[image]

[How to get IntelliJ IDEA to display directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147336/how-to-get-intellij-idea-to-display-directories)
That didn`t help. I need to change something in settings, but I don`t know what exactly.

Comment: Please try deleting all the files and re-creating the file in the directory you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will happen, when .idea folder is deleted or conflicted.

The best way is create new project, so .idea folder will create & all will work fine.

I have also faced same probel, when .idea folder is conflicted or deleted.

To easily create a module for your project and therefore show the folder structure -

Go to File menu -> New -> Project...
Select Static Web. Note: it does not matter if your project is "web" or not!
Hit next, then fill in the same Project Name: and Project location: as you have already.
IntelliJ will say "File Already Exists" - "Would you like to overwrite it?" - answer Yes.